# How to mark table row as urgency in mvc

Tags: jquery, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am having a table in mvc with large amount of data.

I want to mark the table row as highlighted on button click and also i can highlight multiple row on
same button click. And keep it highlighted until user again click on that row. When user again click on same row unhighlight it.

Comment: Javascript and CSS

Comment: i had done it but when you refresh the page it remove the highlight status. I want to keep it highlighted  even after page is refresh until user not click on that row again

Comment: That is critical information to the post. This will require use of cookies or persisting to a database that can be rebuilt on page refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution by adding a additional field in database
and depending on the value in database it changes background color of row

And after selecting a row on button click change the value in database respectively.

```
$("#tableId tr").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

    //$(this).addClass('selected');
    var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
    //alert(value);

});
```

above code is used to select the row in table

```
$('#buttonId').on('click', function (e) {
   
        var row = $("#tableId tr.selected ");
        var data= {};
        data.ID= row.find(".Id").find("span").html();
        data.Name= row.find(".Name").find("span").html();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Controller/ActionMethod",
        data: '{data:' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"

        });

        window.location.reload();
    
});
```

Above code is used to pass the value to controller

And then update the database using the controller

```
       if(db.dbField== "Yes")
        {
            db.dbField = "NO";
        }
        else
        {
            db.dbField = "Yes";
        }
```